# How can I update user's data by clicking on the edit button?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

Using `php`, I want to make the Edit button in `register.php` to display the form which shows fields that have the already existing user's data and then admin can update the data. I'm about to go crazy because of this thing it's been the third day in row not moving to the second step! I've watched many YT tutorials and explored many solutions here and in google as well, but couldn't actually figure out how to fix mine! Please if you know where my mistake is and what should I edit, do tell me and I will be more than happy to fix it.

These are my files:

**register.php**

```
<?php 

session_start();
    include('includes/header.php');
    include('includes/navbar.php');
?>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addadminprofile">
       Add Admin Profile 
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="addadminprofile" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add Admin Data</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <form action="code.php" method="POST">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Username </label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Full name </label>
            <input type="text" name="full_name" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email </label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password </label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Confirm password </label>
            <input type="password" name="cpassword" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Gender </label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" tabindex="1" value="Male">
                <span>  Male</span>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" tabindex="2" value="Female">
                <span>  Female</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Age </label>
            <input type="text" name="age" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Phone number </label>
            <input type="text" name="phone_number" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Work durationr </label>
            <input type="text" name="work_duration" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label >Food Category:</label>
                <select name="food_category" class="form-control" required>
                <option value="hot_cold_dishes">Hot/Cold Dishes</option>
                <option value="desserts">Desserts</option>
                <option value="drinks">Drinks</option>
                </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>IG Account </label>
            <input type="text" name="ig_account" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label >State:</label>
                <select name="state" class="form-control" required>
                <option value="1">First</option>
                <option value="2">Second</option>
                <option value="3n">Third</option>
                </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Postcode </label>
            <input type="text" name="postcode" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>City </label>
            <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="Submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
      </div>
</form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php
/*
if(isset($_SESSION['success']) && $_SESSION['success'] != ''){

    echo '<h2>'.$_SESSION['success'].'</h2>';
    unset ($_SESSION['success']);
}

if(isset($_SESSION['status']) && $_SESSION['status'] != ''){

    echo '<script>alert('.$_SESSION['status'].')</script>';
    unset ($_SESSION['status']);
}
*/

?>

<div class="card shadow">
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">

    <?php

        $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "finalproject") or die ("<script>alert('Connection Failed.')</script>");

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    ?>
            <table class="table table-borderd" id="dataTable" width="30%" cellspecing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Full Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Password</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Phone Number</th>
                        <th>Work Duration</th>
                        <th>Food Category</th>
                        <th>IG Account</th>
                        <th>State</th>
                        <th>Postcode</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php

                    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                            ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['username']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['full_name']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['email']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['password']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['phone_number']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['work_duration']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['food_category']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['ig_account']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['state']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['postcode']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['city']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['gender']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['age']?></td>
                        <td>
                            <form action="first_register.php" method="POST">
                              <input type="hidden" name="edit_username" value="<?php echo $row['username'];?>">
                            <button type="submit" name="edit_button" class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "No record found";
                    }

                    ?>
                </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>


<?php
include('includes/script.php');
include('includes/footer.php');
?>
```

**first_register.php**

```
<?php 
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "finalproject")or die ("<script>alert('Connection Failed.')</script>");

session_start();
    include('includes/header.php');
    include('includes/navbar.php');
?>

<div class="container-fluid">

<!-- DataTales Example -->
<div class="card shadow mb-4">
    <div class="card-header py-3">
        <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary"> EDIT Admin Profile </h6>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
    <?php

    
if(isset($_POST['edit_button']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE username='$username' ";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    foreach($query_run as $row)
    {
        ?>

            <form action="code.php" method="POST">

                <input type="hidden" name="edit_username" value="<?php echo $row['username'] ?>">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label> Full name </label>
                    <input type="text" name="edit_full_name" value="<?php echo $row['full_name'] ?>" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="edit_email" value="<?php echo $row['email'] ?>" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Enter Email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="edit_password" value="<?php echo $row['password'] ?>"
                        class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Gender</label>
                                <input type="radio" name="edit_gender" value="Male" class="form-control">
                                <span>  Male</span>
                                <input type="radio" name="edit_gender" value="Female" class="form-control">
                                <span>  Female</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Age</label>
                                <input type="text" name="edit_age" value="<?php echo $row['age'] ?>"
                                    class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Phone Number</label>
                                <input type="text" name="edit_phone_number" value="<?php echo $row['phone_number'] ?>"
                                    class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Work Duration</label>
                                <input type="text" name="edit_work_duration" value="<?php echo $row['work_duration'] ?>"
                                    class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Food Category</label>
                                <select name="food_category" class="form-control" required>
                                <option value="hot_cold_dishes">Hot/Cold Dishes</option>
                                <option value="desserts">Desserts</option>
                                <option value="drinks">Drinks</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>IG Account</label>
                                <input type="text" name="edit_ig_account" value="<?php echo $row['ig_account'] ?>"
                                    class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>State</label>
                                <select name="state" class="form-control" required>
                                <option value="1">First</option>
                                <option value="2">Second</option>
                                <option value="3n">Third</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Postcode</label>
                                <input type="text" name="edit_postcode" value="<?php echo $row['postcode'] ?>"
                                    class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>City</label>
                                <input type="text" name="edit_city" value="<?php echo $row['city'] ?>"
                                    class="form-control">
                            </div>

                            <form action="edit_register.php" method="POST">
                              <input type="hidden" name="edit_username" value="<?php echo $row['username'];?>">
                            <button type="submit" name="edit_button" class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
                            </form>

            </form>
            <?php
    }
}
  
        ?>


<?php
include('includes/script.php');
include('includes/footer.php');
?>
```

**edit_register.php**

```
<?php 
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "finalproject")or die ("<script>alert('Connection Failed.')</script>");

session_start();
    include('includes/header.php');
    include('includes/navbar.php');
?>

<div class="card shadow">
<div class="card-header">
    <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-primary">EDIT Profile  </h6>
</div>
<div class="card_body">

<?php

if(isset($_POST['updatebtn']))
{
    $username2 = $_POST['edit_username'];
    $full_name2 = $_POST['edit_full_name'];
    $email2 = $_POST['edit_email'];
    $password2 = $_POST['edit_password'];
    $cpassword2 = $_POST['cpassword'];
    $phone_number2 = $_POST['edit_phone_number'];
    $work_duration2 = $_POST['edit_work_duration'];
    $food_category2 = $_POST['edit_food_category'];
    $ig_account2 = $_POST['edit_ig_account'];
    $state2 = $_POST["edit_state"];
    $postcode2 = $_POST['edit_postcode'];
    $city2 = $_POST['edit_city'];
    $gender2 = $_POST['edit_gender'];
    $age2 = $_POST['edit_age'];
    
    $query = "UPDATE users SET username='$username2', full_name='$full_name2', email='$email2', password='$password2', phone_number='$phone_number2', word_duration='$work_duration2', food_category='$food_category2', 
    ig_account='$ig_account2', state='$state2', postcode='$postcode2', city='$city2', gender='$gender2', age='$age2' WHERE username='$username2'";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if($query_run)
    {
        $_SESSION['status'] = "Your Data is Updated";
        $_SESSION['status_code'] = "success";
        header('Location: register.php'); 
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['status'] = "Your Data is NOT Updated";
        $_SESSION['status_code'] = "error";
        header('Location: register.php'); 
    }
?>


      <?php
}

?>
</div>
<?php
include('includes/script.php');
include('includes/footer.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

At *register.php,* you have this line this -

```
<input type="hidden" name="edit_username" value="<?php echo $row['username'];?>">
```

So at *first_register.php,* you should have this line like this instead -

```
 $username = $_POST['username']; to $username = $_POST['edit_username'];
```

and this line like this instead -

```
<form action="code.php" method="POST"> to <form action="edit_register.php" method="POST">
```

i could see you have a form inside a another form like this

```
<form action="edit_register.php" method="POST">
     <input type="hidden" name="edit_username" value="<?php echo $row['username'];?>">
     <button type="submit" name="edit_button" class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
 </form>
```

//remove the form tag to this only since you have input for edit_username aready at the top of your form

```
         <button type="submit" name="edit_button" class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
```

//and finally at edit_register.php change

```
if(isset($_POST['updatebtn']))
 to if(isset($_POST['edit_button']))
```

I guess this should help achieve the goal. good luck